# How to connect to a local server in Oracle SQL Developer like SQL*Plus with no TNSlistener?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-sql-developer

How can I use SQL Developer to connect to a local Oracle 11g server?  I didn't enable TNS Listener, but SQL*Plus works well.

@update1:

---

I copied all *.jars from `$ORACLE_HOME/app/product/11.2.0/dbhome_2/jdbc/lib/` to `jdbc` directory in SQLDeveloper

And I get error: `no ocijdbc11 in java.library.path`

So I traced down sqldeveloper.sh , and add some parameters to it:

[image: modified script to add library path]

However , another error discovered:

[image: error dialog B]

Certain wired string kept changing each time i connect

@update2:

---

If only I add

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/Application/Binaries/oracle_11g/app/product/11.2.0/dbhome_2/jdbc/lib
```

I'll get the following error:

[image: error when all jdbc libraries added]

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Developer, use the *Local/Bequeath* connection type:

[image: New connection dialogue]

Answer (score 0):

SQLplus uses IPC to directly communicate with the instance, and I don't think SQLdeveloper has that option. Try the method described in this thread: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=428671

Comment: Mixing Oracle 11g's into SQLdeveloper's classpath doesn't seem like the best idea (it's probably what cauese the random error messages). Just add the odbc*.jars to the classpath you've copied. ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath )

Comment: sqldeveloper is latest version , just grabbed from oracle's site today